# Remove an element ( and its children ) from the DOM

Tags: javascript

Via the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.) I want to simply do:

```
parent_element.removeChild(child_element);
```

However, in this particular case `child_element` has its own child elements.

Can I assume that this will not cause any problems and that they too will be removed.

The examples given in the reference did not make complete sense.

Comment: Why don't you just [try it out for yourself](http://jsfiddle.net/) and see if this is true or not?

Comment: Your example have nothing

Comment: @SpikeX `Can I assume that this will not cause any problem` - you can't try that out for yourself

Comment: Well, since OP didn't post any specific code it's sort of hard to answer that question anyway. And he ashed if "they too will be removed", which is definitely easy to write some quick code and test for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all elements that are childs of a removed element are removed. You don't need to implement a deep removal yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Yes when you remove an element from the DOM, all of its children are removed with it.  If you are working with a modern browser, this is pretty safe.  Older browsers tended to get memory leaks if you did not first remove all your event handlers before removing the elements.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can assume that the child's children will be removed

Answer (score -2):

If the children didnt get removed, where or how could they exist in the DOM, unless someone put them somewhere else.